# Android Navigation Drawer Implementation

Tags: android, android-navigation

Previously, I used ImageButtons to navigate through Activities. Now I am going to make a standard Left Navigation Drawer. But the Application need to Extend Activity where as the Default Navigation includes Extend NavigationDrawerActivity. How to Handle this?
I need something like:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

//Bla Bla Bla

}
```

And the Drawer Sample App already has this piece of cake:

```
public class Main extends ActionBarActivity implements 

    NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

        private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
            //This and that


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [ActionBarActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) already extends the [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) class so if your activity extends `ActionBarActivity` nothing you have will break.

(You will need to have support library v7 in order for you to be able to extend `ActionBarActivity`)